# Behat with Mink

Tags: php, bdd, behat

Does anyone know how to successfully configure Mink to work with Behat? In case if anyone doesn't know, Behat is a BDD(Behaviour-Driven Development) framework for PHP and Mink provides a browser emulators abstraction layer to test with.

You can find out more about Behat at http://behat.org/ and Mink at https://github.com/Behat/Mink or http://www.knplabs.com/fr/blog/one-mink-to-rule-them-all

Basically i followed the instructions at http://www.knplabs.com/fr/blog/one-mink-to-rule-them-all to configure my Mink to work with my Behat. My *behat.yml*, the one located inside the Behat folder, not the Mink folder, is as follows:

```
default:
  paths:
    features:               %%BEHAT_CONFIG_PATH%%/features
    formatter:
    name:                   progress
pretty:
  formatter:
    name:                   pretty
    parameters:
      multiline_arguments:  false
default:
    environment:
        parameters:
            start_url: http://localhost/
imports:
    - mink/behat.yml
```

I also have the following code in my **features/support/boostrap.php**

```
require_once 'mink/autoload.php';
```

However, having the following code in my **features/support/env.php**

```
$world->client = new \Goutte\Client;
```

would give me a **PHP Fatal error:  Class 'Goutte\Client' not found** in terminal(OSX) when i use the behat command. This happens even if i have the **goutte.phar** inside my **behat/Mink/Vendor/Goutte** folder.

Hope anyone can enlighten me on where i went wrong and if there was any part in the question where I wasn't being clear about it, do let me know. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Here it is: https://github.com/knplabs/mink-demo ;-)

Basically, with Mink, you don't need to create or require Goutte client it's done by Mink automatically. Your $world was also enhanced and now you're able to get mink session inside step definitions:

```
$downloadsLink = $world->getSession()->getPage()->findLink('downloads');
```

Also, you've forgot to include PHPUnit!

See mink-demo for getting great example ;-)

Comment: thanks alot for the great info provided =) just another problem cropped up for me though~ i got this error when i use the behat command in the demo -> PHP Warning:  preg_match(): Unknown modifier 'w' in /usr/local/pear/share/pear/behat/src/Behat/Behat/Definition/DefinitionDispatcher.php on line 185 ' Given I am on /wiki/Main_Page'. Could it be due to it's step definition which is:  $steps->Given('/^I am on /wiki/Main_Page$/', function($world) {
    //throw new \Behat\Behat\Exception\Pending();
}); or i am thinking it could be some configuration mistake on my part. Thanks a lot.

Comment: i found out the reason why i got that error. It was due to incorrect regex in the step definition. The step definition for that line should be: $steps->Given('/^I am on \/wiki\/Main_Page$/', function($world) ... so as to treat the slash infront of wiki to be just a slash but not making the 'w' a modifier. However, now that that error is gone, i get a new error message saying that: Error: Call to undefined method Behat\Behat\Environment\Environment::getSession in steps/ajax.php on line 12 where i have $world->getSession()->wait(5000, "$('.suggestions-results').children().length > 0");

Comment: Just install latest Behat, Mink and follow ALL THE instructions from link!

Comment: make sure your ymls are formatted correctly or you will have a bad time. the tech that parses it is very sensitive to spaces and tabs